# Update array PDO

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I was working with this code:

```
$sortId = $_POST['sortId'];
$sortName = $_POST['sortName'];
$sortType = $_POST['sortType'];
$location = $_POST['location'];
$active = $_POST['active'];

$sql = "UPDATE `sorts` SET `sort` = :sort
WHERE `sort_id` = :sort_id"; 

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':sort', $sort);
$stmt->bindParam(':sort_id', $sort_id);

$db->beginTransaction();

foreach($sortName as $i => $sort)
{
    $sort_id = $sortId[$i];
    $stmt->execute(); 
}
$db->commit();
```

It works as it should so I proceeded to add extra values

```
$sortId = $_POST['sortId'];
    $sortName = $_POST['sortName'];
    $sortType = $_POST['sortType'];
    $location = $_POST['location'];
    $active = $_POST['active'];

    $sql = "UPDATE `sorts` SET `sort` = :sort, `shipping_sort` = :sortType
    WHERE `sort_id` = :sort_id"; 

    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':sort', $sort);
    $stmt->bindParam(':sort_id', $sort_id);
    $stmt->bindParam(':sortType', $sortType);

    $db->beginTransaction();

    foreach($sortName as $i => $sort)
    {
        $sort_id = $sortId[$i];
        $stmt->execute(); 
    }
    $db->commit();
```

HTML

```
 <div class="chuteAudit">
        <div>
          <input  type="hidden" name="sortId[]" value="<?php echo $name['sort_id']; ?>" >
          <input  type="text" name="sortName[]" value="<?php echo $name['sort']; ?>" >
          <select name="sortType[]" >
                                  <optgroup label="<?php echo $name['shipping_sort'] ?>">
                                      <option value="amzl[]">AMZL</option>
                                      <option value="other[]">Other</option>
                                  </optgroup>
        </select>
          <select name="location[]" >
                                  <option value=""><?php echo $name['section'] ?></option>
                                  <option value="chutes">Chutes</option>
                                  <option value="spine">Spine</option>
                                  <option value="RMspine">Royal Mail spine</option>
                                  <option value="RMchutes">Royal Mail chutes</option>
                                  <option value="exceptions">Exceptions</option>
                                  <option value="teamLift">Team lift</option>
            </select>
            <select name="active[]" >
                                  <option value=""><?php echo $name['active'] ?></option>
                                  <option value="yes">Yes</option>
                                  <option value="no">No</option>
            </select>
        </div>

      </div>
```

I had assumed this would be fine as it's only adding onto something that already works however it's not quite as simple as I originally thought it would be, currently I'm getting the error message `Notice: Array to string conversion`  I know it's relating to the additional code I added but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

having `sortType[]` in your form makes your `$sortType` an array.

you bind the array here:

```
$stmt->bindParam(':sortType', $sortType); //$sortType is an array
```

what you need to bind is more like

```
$stmt->bindParam(':sortType', $sort_type);
```

And then add to foreach

```
foreach($sortName as $i => $sort)
{
    $sort_id = $sortId[$i];
    $sort_type = $sortType[$i];
    $stmt->execute(); 
}
```

similiar to how you iterate through sortId, iterate through sortType

Comment: Ah of course, thank you, I'll accept the answer when it lets me.